# Build Python-Executable to run on a PC without having Python installed

Tags: python, pyqt, exe, pyinstaller

I am currently developing a python program with pyqt5. 
I want to give my program to other people. Therefore I want to build an executable for my python programm, so they don't need to have python installed.
I did some research and tried to build an executable with the tool pyinstaller. Therefore I put my python-file and images (.png), that I use in a directroy:

```py
"D:\Test"
```

I used the command "pyinstaller application.py" to build an executable file. After running this command three new directories were build: **pychache**, build and dist.
When I run the executable, I got an Error with "PyQt5.sip" and a windows plugin. So I added the directory with the PyQt5 plugins "platforms" (with e. g. qwindows.dll) in my dist directory. 
Then I added "PyQt5.sip" in the .spec-file:

```py
...hiddenimports=["PyQt5.sip"],...
```

Then I am able to run the executablle-file in my dist-directory. The problem is that my friend, who has not installed python, is not able to run the executable. And this I what I don't really understand. Because I mean I want to build that exe-file so he does not have to install python. Am I missing here something? If someone has an idea or knows how to do that, I would be very grateful.

The ErrorMessage says:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "application.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\users\zz4433\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py" line 627, in exec_module
  File "PyQt5\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
  File "PyQt5\__init__.py", line 33, in find_qt
ImportError: unable to finde Qt5Core.dll on PATH
[29684] Failed to execute script application
```

I googled for an answer for this error message but I wasn't very successful. Does anyone know an answer? That would be great!

Comment: yes, I tried that too...But with the same error

Comment: I don't think you can run python scripts without installing python on your system.. because it will just be a text file with funny extension. You can run it if you install Docker and then run it using Docker..

Comment: Well I gave my friend a simple python program for tests. He was able to run the python-exe. But somehow there are problems with using PyQt....

Comment: @DennisJensen so I can build an executable with NSIS where Python and everything gets installed on the other PC?

Comment: Have a look at this: [https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4293](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4293).

Comment: @Geeky29 I do not understand your comment to me -- you originally stated "Therefore I want to build an executable for my python program, so they don't need to have python installed." but your comment seems to contradict that.

Answer (score 0):

If you tried pyinstaller --onefile myprog.py but still it shows error then the problem is your pyinstaller version cannot able to build all modules and create executable because you use pyqt5 try to use latest version of pyinstaller